# Service Account Authentication fails with gsutil for DCM CS bucket(Google-owned API Console Project)

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, gsutil

I've done an extensive research but I can't find a solution.

How can I enable Service Account Authentication for a project that is linked with Google's private owned Bucket for Double Click Manager data? (more info on the current setup of this project here https://support.google.com/dcm/partner/answer/2941575?hl=en&ref_topic=6107456&rd=1).

Separate user authentication works with gsutil(navigating to browser->get token->paste back in your cmd->issue commands) but when it comes to configuring a service account I keep getting

```
AccessDeniedException: 403 Forbidden
```

What am I missing? Since the Google documentation says that this specific bucket can't be listed under Cloud Storage for that project, then the project and the service account should be linked to that bucket by default so I can't see the issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During set-up you should have created a Google Group to control access to your bucket. You should add the service account email address to that group, and it will then be able to access the bucket.